# Select Items from a List while changing their Col Name in R

Tags: r, list, select, data.table

So I am using this code for selecting items from a list:

```
itemSelect<- list.select(List,sha,commit$author$date,commit$author$name,
commit$author$email,
commit$message,committer$type)
```

And then I convert to data table:

```
df<-list.rbind(itemSelect)
dt<-as.data.table(df)
```

But when I see my data table the col names of the items I selecter are changed except the sha.

I think that's because the item "sha" was the first one on the list. But the other ones where variable of variables with "$". And the col name became:

```
 sha        V2           V3        V4        V5         V6
d34sx   20-10-2015   23-10-2015    Nic    Comments     user
dftwr   21-11-2015   03-09-2015    Pic    Comments2    user
```

So I want to ask if there is a way while selecting Items from a list also changing the col name? Or should I find a way to mass change the col name after I convert it to data table?

Thanx!

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example? We don't have your `commit` object or the functions `list.select` or `list.rbind`

Comment: A reproducible example would help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sent the names using:

```
names(dt) <- c("sha","author_date","author_name","author_email","message","type")
```

Comment: Worked great thanx!